# Vue telegram webapp bot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, telegram, telegram-bot

Good afternoon. I decided to integrate a web app into my chat bot. New telegram feature.

but for some reason, after adding the site, an empty page opens on the button. As I was able to find out, the problem is in some js that vue pulls up.

P.S. just going through the domain site feels great.

Apparently the built-in telegram browser forbids something from what vue uses

The question is, how do I debug? After all, I can't even copy text from this window, let alone the developer's console in this window.

Comment: please include some of the code you're referencing

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of what you're seeing in Telegram vs what you're seeing when loading the URL directly in your web browser?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The decision came from where they did not expect.
The problem is with the PC version.
How could I figure out the point is that.
TDesktop on a PC cannot use TLS 1.3.

Everything is great on the phone!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).